# Javascript function / undefined error - tip calculation

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

While learning JavaScript and trying to solve a challenge question, my code keeps outputting 'undefined value'.

My code:

```
function paidAmount(bill){
var tipPercent
if (bill < 50){
    tipPercent = 0.20;
}
else if (bill >= 50 && bill <=200){
    tipPercent = 0.15;
}
else{
    tipPercent = 0.10;
}
return bill * tipPercent;
}

var tip1 = console.log(paidAmount(124));
var tip2 = console.log(paidAmount(48));
var tip3 = console.log(paidAmount(268));

var tipTotal = [tip1, tip2, tip3];

console.log(tipTotal);
```

Output:

```
18.599999999999998
9.600000000000001
26.8
(3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: The `console.log()` function *always* returns `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign values which are inside `console.log`. Make them separate

```js
function paidAmount(bill){
var tipPercent
if (bill < 50){
    tipPercent = 0.20;
}
else if (bill >= 50 && bill <=200){
    tipPercent = 0.15;
}
else{
    tipPercent = 0.10;
}
return bill * tipPercent;
}


var tip1 = paidAmount(124);
var tip2 = paidAmount(48);
var tip3 = paidAmount(268);
console.log(paidAmount(124));
console.log(paidAmount(268));
console.log(paidAmount(48));
var tipTotal = [tip1, tip2, tip3];

console.log(tipTotal);
```

Comment: If it helped you upvote and mark it correct so it can help others too

Comment: Why repeat the calculation? you should've done `console.log(tip1)`. DRY.

Answer (score 0):

console.log returns undefined.  See the specs linked below for more information.

[Namespace Console spec link](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#console-namespace)

[Namspace Console spec image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noypD.png)

[Logger spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger)

Also, in your example, you don't have to store the results into the variables tip1, tip2, tip3.

Instead you could directly call the paidAmount inside of console.log:

```
console.log(paidAmount(124), paidAmount(48), paidAmount(268));
```

Answer (score 0):

`[console.log(tip1),console.log(tip2),...]` is *wrong*, but you can try another way :

```js
function paidAmount(bill) {
  var tipTotal = [] ;
  var tipPercent ;

  for (value of bill) {
    tipPercent = (value < 50 ) ? 0.20 : ( ( value >= 50 && value <= 200) ? 0.15 : 0.10 ) ;
    tipTotal.push( value * tipPercent ) ;
  }

  return tipTotal ;
}

console.log( paidAmount([124, 48, 268]) );
```